# How can I find the age of a record in minutes when using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, time

I have a history table with a `datetime` field named `createdAt`. I'm trying to determine the age of the record but the age column comes back as `Null`:

```
SELECT id, (MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),IFNULL(history.createdAt,0)))) AS age
FROM history
WHERE history.type = @type
```

I tried `DATEDIFF()` instead of `TIMEDIFF()` and I get a `0` back

Any idea why this query is not behaving as expected?

**UPDATE:**

After introspecting the database, I found that the `createdAt` column was a `date` and not a `datetime` column. The code works as expected if using a `datetime` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to test right now, but the API says:

> Returns the minute for time, in the
>   range 0 to 59.

```
mysql> SELECT MINUTE('2008-02-03 10:05:03');
        -> 5
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute

-- not what you want to do. Try TIME_TO_SEC() on the result from TIMEDIFF, and divide it by 60 to get minutes.

Comment: I think it was the TIMEDIFF() function. I switched to to DATEDIFF() since createdAt is a datetime field. Now the value comes back as 0. Still doesn't work, but a step closer.

Comment: @Mohamad: DATEDIFF=Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation. TIMEDIFF is what you want, but it needs two values of the same type. Also, to get a positive result, you should have NOW() as the first parameter.

Comment: my table column was set to date and not datetime :/ - thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time. But I did learn something!