# MySQL - Age in minutes

Tags: mysql

This is a pretty simple homework problem that I've been stuck on for a while. Can someone show  me how to go about solving this?

A baby is born on March 1 2012 12:00:00. How old will he be in minutes on July 4th 2013 13:30:00?

Comment: If you are storing the birthdate in an [appropriate datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html), then this should be trivial.

Comment: related : [stackoverflow.com/questions/5035817...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035817/how-can-i-find-the-age-of-a-record-in-minutes-when-using-mysql)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Answer (score 2):

Use this query

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2012-03-01', '2013-07-04')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF()` to count the difference in days, than multiply it by 24 * 60 * 60 (number of seconds in a day)..

Comment: I forgot to include this. What if I am given a minute and second value for each date. So the question would be:
A baby is born on March 1 2012 12:00:00. How old will he be in minutes on July 4th 2013 13:30:00?